# UIAutomation, pause application if Help window appears

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-automation

This is related to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793040/if-i-programmatically-activate-a-window-in-another-application-can-i-detect-whe).

I used the `OnStructureChanged` event to detect that the 'Help' window popped up in the 3rd party application that my application is writing data to.  I need my application to pause while the end user resolves the data issue in the 3rd party application, then I need my application to resume once the end user closes the 'Help' window.  (Either I need to detect that the 'Help' window was closed or I need to display a message box and use the `DialogResult` to trigger my application to resume).

I've never encountered something like this before.  I don't know if it's possible to do what I want to do.  If it is possible, I don't know where to start.

Advice?

---

**UPDATES:**

I have only used Threading once before and I think it was a fairly "easy peasy" usage, I pulled it off without much effort, considering I'd never used Threading before.  I'm playing around with Threading for this issue right now.  There's a good chance I've implemented it incorrectly, but my app isn't functioning correctly anymore...I don't know if I'm even playing with the correct tool.

Comment: Would you mind posting some code so I can take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

I had to just keep moving with the project - deadlines, you know...

I ended up using UI Automation to detect the "Help" window, then I showed a message box giving instructions to the end user.  I check the MessageBox's DialogResult and continue processing based on that.  It might not be the "best" way to skin the cat, but I'm a noob and I have a deadline, so I did what I needed to do to keep moving.